# from X given numbers find all groups of 5 whose sum is equal or under a given number

Tags: arrays

Specifically, we have 20 numbers (X1, X2, ...,X20).
I want to find every group of 5 that is equal or under 100

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this as arrays, please use this pseudo code:

Please note that I have used a bi-dimensional array:

```
array = [12, 5, 129, 87, 43, 2, 0, 4, 1, 900, 45, 999, 99, 34, 7, 231, 4, 8, 65, -3]
groupArray = [][]
groupCounter = 0
groupCounterIndex = 0


for i = 0 to count(array) - 1
  if array[i] <= 100 then
    print("The number " array[i] " is less or equal than 100")
    groupArray[groupCounterIndex][array[i]]
    groupCounter = groupCounter + 1
    if groupCounter = 5 then
       groupCounterIndex = groupCounterIndex + 1
  end
next
```

The result will be:

groupArray[0][12, 5, 87, 43, 2]

groupArray[1][2, 0, 4, 1, 45]

groupArray[2][99, 34, 7, 4, 8]

Regards,

Carlos Mena